# Autofold #ifdef..#endif in vim via .vimrc

Tags: vim, folding

I have seen partial solutions over the internet but none that really satisfied me: what do I have to put into my .vimrc (ideally I don't want to chance any syntax/*.vim file) such that in all .c/cpp/h files that I open, I get automatic folding of `#ifdef ... #endif` sections?

Comment: What foldmethod are you using? Syntax folding?

Comment: Yes, syntax folding (but I guess I could which if this eases automatic folding)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the only type of folding that you want is the `#ifdef` sections, the easiest way is to create a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` (you may also need to do this in `cpp.vim`, I'm not sure) with the following content:

```
set foldmarker=#ifdef,#endif
set foldmethod=marker
```

If you really want to put it in `.vimrc` rather than using the `~/.vim/after/` structure, you can do something like this:

```
autocmd FileType *.[ch]{,pp} call FoldPreprocessor()
function! FoldPreprocessor()
    set foldmarker=#ifdef,#endif
    set foldmethod=marker
endfunction
```

You might also want to consider using:

```
set foldmarker=#if,#endif
```

As that will catch `#if defined(...)`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#if 0` etc as well as `#ifdef`.

Doing this with syntax folding is more challenging as you'll have to change the syntax specification as it doesn't support this as standard.

Comment: vim already has a C syntax folding, but it does not fold the #x. How to add this to the automatic C syntax folding?

Comment: The `*.[ch]{,pp}` pattern does not work for me on a `cpp` file, neither does `*.cpp`. When I use just `*` it works. Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 7):

You know that you can navigate preprocessor conditional blocks with the <kbd>%</kbd> key?

Also, <kbd>[#</kbd> and <kbd>]#</kbd> navigate up/down.

So you could go to the start of a conditional block (perhaps with <kbd>/</kbd>`^#`<kbd>Enter</kbd>), then

```
 zf%               -- fold to next conditional directive
 v2]#zf            -- fold to second next directive (e.g. #else... #endif)
```

`zd` to drop the fold.

Perhaps you can devise a little script around this concept. I'm not very sure whether there will be (adverse) interaction with the regular syntax folding, since I'm not in the habit of using that. I usually use indent folding with manual fold manipulation like this.

Answer (score 0):

This should catch `#if`, `#ifdef`, and `#ifndef`:

```
function! FoldtextForC()
    " Show the whole #if line
    return getline(v:foldstart)
endfun
set foldtext=FoldtextForC()
set foldmarker=#if,#endif
```

After running `:g/#ifdef DEBUG/foldclose` to close some folds on [this code sample](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/98b1cc82c4affc16f5598d4fa14b1858671b2263/fs/efs/super.c#L178-L233) will look like this (`set foldcolumn=3` so you can see the folding):

[image: some linux code folded]

You could tweak `FoldtextForC` to return more information -- see `:h fold-foldtext`:

```
return printf("+%s %s", v:folddashes, getline(v:foldstart))
```